# Django template error for include tag

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-templates

I am getting an error message while adding a template to base.html with include tag. All other templates are rendered properly with no issues but this got issues while I try to add it. The error is:

```
RuntimeError at /
maximum recursion depth exceeded in __instancecheck__
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 1.8.5
Exception Type: RuntimeError
Exception Value:    
maximum recursion depth exceeded in __instancecheck__
Exception Location: C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py in __init__, line 743
Python Executable:  C:\Python27\python.exe
Python Version: 2.7.11
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\TOSHIBA\\market\\market',
 'C:\\WINDOWS\\SYSTEM32\\python27.zip',
 'C:\\Python27\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk',
 'C:\\Python27',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages',
 'c:\\python27\\lib\\site-packages']
```

My template I am trying to add includes:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
  <!-- recommend slider -->
  <section class="recommend container">
    <div class="recommend-product-slider small-pr-slider wow bounceInUp">
      <div class="slider-items-products">
        <fieldset class="box-title">
        <legend>Recommended </legend>
        </fieldset>
        <div id="recommend-slider" class="product-flexslider hidden-buttons">
          <div class="slider-items slider-width-col3">
          {% include 'products/product.html' with object_list=products col_class_set="col-sm-2" %}


          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <!-- End Recommend slider -->

{% endblock content %}
```

My base.html code is as follows:

```
{% load static %}
{% load staticfiles %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<!--[if IE]>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<![endif]-->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta name="description" content="Dressika Theme">
<meta name="author" content="Harira Ijaz">
<title>Dressika Online Shopping Store</title>
<!-- Favicons Icon -->
<link rel="icon" href="{% static 'images/favicon.png' %}" type="image/x-icon" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="{% static 'images/favicon.png' %}" type="image/x-icon" />
<!-- Mobile Specific -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<!-- CSS Style -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/animate.css' %}" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/revslider.css' %}" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/owl.carousel.css' %}" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/owl.theme.css' %}" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/font-awesome.css' %}" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/product-detail.css' %}" type="text/css">
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Google Fonts -->
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,300,700,800,400,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>

<body class="cms-index-index">
<div class="page"> 


{% include 'header.html' %}

{% include 'navbar.html' %}
</div>

  <!-- header service -->

  <!-- end header service -->


{% include 'slider.html' %}
{% include 'offerbanner.html' %}
{% include 'container.html' %}

{% include 'featured.html' %}
{% include 'trending.html' %}


{% include 'middleslider.html' %}

{% include 'recommend.html' %}
{% include 'latestblog.html' %}
{% include 'footer.html' %}


</div>
{% include 'java.html' %}
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your template extends from base.html which then needs to include the template, which then needs to extend from base.html which  then needs to include the template, which then needs to extend from base.html  then needs to include the template, which then needs to extend from base.html...

Remove `{% extends 'base.html' %}` from the template you're trying to include as well as any reference to blocks.

Comment: The error is gone and I can see the homepage fine. But the template I've included as 'recommend.html isn't showing products on homepage. Any thought for that?

Comment: @HariraIjaz - No idea, possibly some problem with what is passed as `object_list` but that is a separate question, so you should ask a new question about that if need be. If this answer has helped solved *this* question, then you should consider accepting it.